How to set up Ivy with Netbeans and Ant, to compiler would see resolved libraries?
I am trying to setup Ivy to load some dependencies, but I can't reach the result, my imports just aren`t visible by compiler, it writes that that package doesn't exist. In Netbeans I have the folder lib added in properties (to classpath). So maybe I configured the build.xml wrong. I ask you suggest me where the problem might hide.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="myproj" basedir="." xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" default="go">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project myproj.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
    
    
    <target name="go" depends="compile">
        <java classname="${main.class}" classpathref="classpath"/>
    </target>
    
    <target name="compile" depends="resolve"></target>

    <target name="resolve" description="--> retrieve dependencies with Ivy">
        <ivy:retrieve/>
        <path id="build.path">
            <fileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        </path>
    </target>


    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>
    <property name="main.class" value="finmon.JFrameMain"/>
    
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="."/>
    </path>

</project>

I have correct resolve by Ivy. Also, now I launch the only file with new libs, in psvm
